Can `split_view` or a composition of multiple `spilt_view`s be used to split a `string`/`string_view` using multiple delimiters?
I'm attempting to understand how views can be composed and the limitations of the same.
The idea here is to split a string/string_view without creating a temporary variable as shown in the second code block.
Why does the following not compile:
std::string line = "1[2]3";
for (const auto split : line 
                        | std::ranges::views::split('[') 
                        | std::ranges::views::transform([](const auto rng) {return std::string_view(rng); }) 
                        | std::ranges::views::split(']') 
                        | std::ranges::views::transform([](const auto rng) {return std::string_view(rng); })) {
    std::cout << split << '\n';
}


An additional question is why the above code fails to compile but the following work:
for (const auto split_once : line 
                             | std::ranges::views::split('[')
                             | std::ranges::views::transform([](const auto rng) {return std::string_view(rng); })) {
    for (const auto split_twice : split_once 
                                     | std::ranges::views::split(']') 
                                     | std::ranges::views::transform([](const auto rng) {return std::string_view(rng); })) {
            std::cout << split_twice << '\n';
   }
}

Link to compiler explorer

The first one doesn't seem to neither have balanced { and } nor balanced ( and ). Include the error message in the question.

@TedLyngmo thanks for pointing out the typo. The error message is quite long; in case you missed it, there's a link to compiler explorer where the error is visible.

The first views::transform produces a range whose elements are of type string_view, which cannot be simply split by the character ']'.
Instead, you can continue to split each single string_view and join them together, for example
std::string line = "1[2]3";
for (const auto split : line 
                        | std::ranges::views::split('[')
                        | std::ranges::views::transform(
                            std::ranges::views::split(']') |
                            std::ranges::views::transform(
                              [](auto rng) {return std::string_view(rng); })
                          )
                        | std::views::join) {
    std::cout << split << '\n';
}

Demo

std::views is the shorthand for std::ranges::views. You can go one step further and inject the namespace in the scope that its used(just before the for loop):{using namespace std::views; for/*...*/};. The scoping braces limit the visibility of namespace and minimize probability of name collision, while leading to more succinct code.

Thank you for your answer!
Could you expand the answer to explain why the second code block in the question works where the output from transform is piped into split but stored as a named variable first?
Also, with reference to your answer, why does the second split work when called within transform but not outside it (i.e. how does the transform function modify/affect the input to allow the second split to work correctly)?

@vss2sn Because the type of split_once is string_view, which can be split by the single character ']'.
